# Can't find form with mechanize

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, mechanize

If you view the source of the below link you will see two forms, I am looking to select the one with name="doLoginPin". When I do the below the form is not found. Is this form being generated dynamically therefore it cannot be found? Has anyone ran into this before and come up with a solution?

```
br.open('https://www.getipass.com/ipass/LoginPin.jsp')

for f in br.forms():
    print f
```

Ultimately my goal is to get logged in and scrape some of my basic account data. Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you just send the appropriate request to whatever address the form is sending your data to?

Comment: @RyanO'Donnell how would I go about that? The form action is action="LoginPin.jsp"

Comment: Take a look at the requests library: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to do this would be to use [Selenium Webdriver](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp). It allows you to drive a real browser to make requests. It can be a bit heavy weight at times, but I find it useful for these kind of small tasks (I'd recommend using Firefox as the browser to drive).

You can install it with `pip install selenium`.

This script will attempt to login with username `foo` and password `bar`.

```
from selenium import webdriver

if __name__ == '__main__':
    url = 'https://www.getipass.com/ipass/LoginPin.jsp'
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get(url)

    username = driver.find_element_by_name('txtLoginParam')
    password = driver.find_element_by_name('txtPass')
    username.send_keys('foo')
    password.send_keys('bar')
    password.submit()
```